# How to check which points are in a circle?

Tags: java, arrays, geometry

Okay so say there is a grid, which I have stored as a 2 dimensional array, that is 10 by 10.

`int[][] grid = new int[10][10];`

The origin of the grid is at the bottom left, like a normal x y plane, and there is a circle of radius 5 in the centre of the grid at (5,5), like so:

[image: Terrible drawing]

I want to go through this array and basically check which points are inside the circle, but I do not want to loop through the entire array. By default, every point on a corner is not going to be in the circle, so I would want to ignore those, and similarly the points that are close to the corner, etc.

Just the points that are in the circle. I have a much bigger grid and looping through unnecessary stuff that I already know isn't in the circle would waste time. Is there a way to do this? Because, given that I already know the radius and centre of the circle, there should be a nice easy way to go through those points which are in the circle and change them from 0 to -1, for example.

Otherwise, I would stand to lose 100 - 25π ≈ 21.46% time.

BETTER CLARITY: I already know that I can bound the circle with a square, and loop through the points in that square and check each points distance from the centre of the circle (x^2 + y^2 < r^2), but this is what I am trying to avoid, due to the constant overhead every time of checking the bits that aren't in the circle, when I know they are not in the circle beforehand.

Comment: Hint: look for tutorials on drawing a *filled* circle. Basically the idea is to use the equation of a circle to draw individual scanlines.

Comment: You will lose more computing time setting up a complex logic of excluding those points than you would lose computing and checking x^2+y^2<const. Anyway it is not clear what you are asking and what you have tried already

Comment: @OlegSklyar that depends on how big his grid is; the bigger the grid the more time is lost from traversing the extra cells [O(N^2) vs O(N)]; besides if he uses Bresenham to determine the bounds it should not be too costly.

Comment: Unless the loop is doing nothing, you would be losing 21.46% of the time. The percentage would be much smaller, because you can quickly continue with the loop when you determine that the cell is outside the circle.

Comment: @OlegSklyar I don't really see how it's not clear. For example, there is an easy way to just loop through the square around the circle using x^2 + y^2 < const for every point in the square, but as I said, obviously there is going to be at least 20% of the points not in the circle so that is a waste of time. If the circle is huge, this is a lot of wasted computation looping. But yeah, thanks meowsthedog I will check that out.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog surely there are some optimizations that under theoretical conditions will bring a benefit: a fully included square can be traversed without any conditions at all; for the rest there will be some sort of conditions and the best I can think of from the top of my head is to draw a few more straight lines around the circle e.g. 8 or 16 instead of four and use those linear computations as stopping conditions for outward exploring, also mean state thus cost. He will not save 22% of time as it will be complex. but maybe 15%. Now, wether it makes any practical sense is questionable

Comment: @NotAPro There is no question in your text. The title does not correspond the context. There is no evidence of you investing time in finding the solution. All of those are required by this site.

Comment: @OlegSklyar not sure drawing straight lines will be a good enough approximation - he will need to do some heuristic subdivision to make sure that the circle is as one would expect from a naive grid traversal.

Comment: Is your problem to provide an answer per individual point, or to find all the points in the grid which are in the circle?

Comment: @meowgoesthedog (1) 20% theoretical improvement will not reduce this problem from O(n^2) to O(n). (2) Any heuristic will cost more time than a loop and x*x + y*y, but straight lines and outward exploration from the centre with stopping conditions at those lines might really save 10-15%, still at the cost of complexity

Comment: @OlegSklyar The first comment by meowgoesthedog pretty much solves my problem outright, so I don't think my question is unclear. You have made good points to help so I don't really believe you don't understand my problem.

Comment: @OlegSklyar I did not say that the improvement will be 20% (that would be `dasblinkenlight`), and *neither* did I say the **problem** will be reduced to O(N) (although it can be) - I meant that the *extra cost* of grid traversal is O(N^2) while that of using some formula to determine the boundaries is O(N), where N is the dimension of the grid. Anyways I never mentioned about specific percentages because they are dependent on many factors and details about the system, and thus not worth talking about.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, after a long discussion, here is the solution. You scan across one axis of a quarter slice, compute the extension to which you need to fill that quarter outwards and then fill all 4 quarters at once.

```
int n = 1000;

// you will need to think yourself about the odd number or elements
int r = n / 2;
int r2 = r * r;
```

Putting (0,0) at the centre of the matrix in both cases, the optimized solutions can look like this:

```
int[][] grid0 = new int[n][n];
for (int i = 0; i < r; i++) {
    double m = Math.sqrt(r2 - i * i);
    for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
        grid0[r + i][r + j] = 1;
        grid0[r + i][r - j] = 1;
        grid0[r - i][r + j] = 1;
        grid0[r - i][r - j] = 1;
    }
}
```

As commented elsewhere, the extension of filling the circle is computed in O(n).

Here is the straightforward validation:

```
int[][] grid1 = new int[n][n];
// you will need to think yourself about the even number
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        if ((i - r) * (i - r) + (j - r) * (j - r) < r2) {
            grid1[i][j] = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Both produce the same number of filled points.

Time measurements over 10000 executions (with array initialization outside of the time loop):

> the optimized one 6.0s
>
> the exhaustive one 15.6s

So, I do admit there is a difference, an astonishing one. Although for a fair comparison, the latter snippet should also be using a quarter slice of the circle.

One can speed up the optimized solution even further using some sort of memory copy routine to fill the values from 0 to the computed point rather than a plain loop, but that is beyond the scope.

Comment: One can further decrease the time by putting the latter two array assignments in a separate loop to improve cache coherency. Also can use Bresenham's circle algorithm to determine the boundary instead of a square root.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog Agree, there is further room for second-order improvement. The first order is achieved, as OP suggested, by not iterating through elements that are outside of the circle boundary. Turned out to be a more interesting challenge than I originally anticipated.

Comment: By flipping x and y coordinates you could work through 1/8th of a filled circle and the rest would come from copying

Comment: Well yes. And by filling in a fitted square unconditionally you can get further gains. Suggest an edit. It looks though as if the OP lost interest in his question :)